# Python: convert large list to generator?

Tags: python, list, python-multiprocessing

I already have a python list type variable, which holds 6000000 entries of which entry data type is python dictionary.

```
a = [{'a': .... }, {'a': ...} , ...]
```

Since it occupies too many memory so I'd like to convert it to the generator or something.

Problem is that the list variable is the return value of multiprocessing `Pool`, so I can not make a generator in the earlier time.

Any advices?

Comment: Even though you use generator of it, it is already in memory. What is the point?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to a generator"? Where does the list of dicts come from? Do you have an algorithm? Or is it a dataset from disk?

Comment: You can use `iter` to convert it into an iterator. But like @BoseongChoi mentioned what's the point when you already have the list in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it in memory, then converting it to a `generator` won't solve the problem. You would need to make a `generator` which would load entries from a disk on-the-fly, thus not loading all the entries into memory at the same time. [Here](https://www.lachlaneagling.com/reducing-memory-consumption-python/) is a good article on using `generators` in Python to handle memory limitations.

Comment: If I understand correctly your answer, if I don't have a memory problem using a generator won't solve the issue, right?

Comment: If you don't have a memory problem, what is your issue then? Generators are very useful in many cases, one of them is loading things into memory when needed (and not loading all at once), which is the case in this post.

Comment: my issue might be a bit different from this one and I don't want to pollute this thread. Just to complete my question, my problem is the following: I have a big list of floats that needs to be allocated to another variable and this allocation takes a lot of time since the list has 4600000 items.

Comment: You basically want to make a copy of a list with many items or just reference a single list with multiple variables?

Comment: I think the first option

Comment: In such a case I think you cannot do it faster (generators won't help here either). Why do you need a copy of the data? Do you want to change it and keep the original intact?

Comment: I am taking the original and populating a ROS2 custom message with it ([ROS2](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/index.html))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247698/discussion-between-andrejh-and-desmond13).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) to compute the results lazily. This will prevent one large list being generated but instead you can iterate over the results in chunks by supplying the `chunksize` parameter:

```
results_generator = pool.imap(func, input_data, 64)  # chunks of 64
```